# SugarCRM Code Flow

Tags: php, sugarcrm

Actually i am using [sugarCRM](http://www.sugarcrm.com/) open source for my own purpose. That was developed by [PHP](http://php.net) in [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVC) format. I want to do some changes in existing file. I cannot modify the any code at any cost, because i cannot understand the flow of the code. In sugar CRM having many folders and files so that was difficult to understand the code flowing.

Exactly what i am expecting is, atleast one module is how is flowing with the code and what is the exact file path...

Very Big thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the [Sugar Developers](http://developers.sugarcrm.com/) website? There are tutorials and other information about developing for Sugar.

Answer (score 0):

Sugar Developers website is a great source but you could also use [documentation](http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/support/documentation) where you could find for each SugarCRM Flavor a Developer Guide, and since 6.3 an API Documentation and a Schema Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Sugar modules are in /modules but you don't want to edit these as it is not upgrade safe. To make a modification you either use or create the relevant folder in /custom/modules

Most often you will be doing metadata updates (most functionality is metadata driven) in files like editviewdefs.php, listviewdefs.php in the custom folder.

Logic hooks can go in here too, search for logic_hooks.php in the sugar documentation as it shows the way to create the metadata array to reference new PHP functions on hooks like "before_save", "after_save" and others.

Sometimes you can start the customisations in Studio (admin menu) and get examples generated in the custom folder for you.